# Why does Gtk2::Builder mix up my signals?

Tags: perl, gtk, glade, gtkbuilder

I'm having this perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

use Gtk2 '-init';

my $data;

my $builder_file = "lists.glade";

my $builder = Gtk2::Builder->new();
$builder->add_from_file( $builder_file )
    or die "Couldn't read $builder_file";
$builder->connect_signals( undef );


my $window = $builder->get_object( "top_window" )
    or die "Error while setting up GUI";

$window->show_all();

# Dealloc builder
$builder = undef;

Gtk2->main();

sub top_window_destroy_cb
{
    Gtk2->main_quit();
}

sub on_radiobutton1_group_changed
{
    my ($self, $choice) = @_;

    print Dumper($self, $choice, $choice->get_text());
}
```

and this builder file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.16"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="top_window">
    <signal name="destroy" handler="top_window_destroy_cb"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkVButtonBox" id="vbuttonbox1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkRadioButton" id="radiobutton1">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Pera</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">False</property>
                <property name="active">True</property>
                <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
                <signal name="group_changed" handler="on_radiobutton1_group_changed" object="choice"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">False</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkRadioButton" id="radiobutton2">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Mika</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">False</property>
                <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
                <property name="group">radiobutton1</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">False</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="choice">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Choice</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

But it falsely connects "on_radiobutton1_group_changed" with "destroy" signal from "top_window". I know this because it executes "print Dumper..." statement only when closing window. Does anyone has idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The "group-changed" signal
>
> Emitted when the group of radio buttons that a radio button belongs to changes. This is emitted when a radio button switches from being alone to being part of a group of 2 or more buttons, or vice-versa, and when a button is moved from one group of 2 or more buttons to a different one, but not when the composition of the group that a button belongs to changes.

It really doesn't sound like what you want.  I'm guessing it is called on destruction of the window.

I added the following sub

```
sub on_radiobutton_toggled {
    my $self = shift;
    if ($self->get_active) {
        print Dumper($self, $self->get_label);
    }
}
```

and set the each radiobutton's toggled signal (under GtkToggleButton) to on_radiobutton_toggled, which now does what you want.

Comment: What I like about perl-gtk2 is how close it is to the C interface, so devhelp is very helpful even if all the example code is in C.